# I need a cell to be filled with a certain text when two other cells contain a certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I tried to use the countif function and then tried using vlookup and was not really successful.

The condition statement I need is, for example, if L10 contains the word "TAX" and M10 contains the word "USA", cell N10 will automatically fill with the word "VAT" in red, if one of them is missing, leave it blank.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula below in cell `N10` and set the text color to red. Since you want either "VAT" in red or blank, then the blank text can be set to red and it won't matter. No conditional formatting required.

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("tax",L10))),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("usa",M10)))),"VAT","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Engineer Toast, for some reason I get an error message about the formula.

Comment: It works when input into cell `N10` of a new sheet. It should work in any cell except `L10` and `M10` where it would pop up a circular reference error. If either `L10` or `M10` evaluate to an error, the formula will be accepted but return an error. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Thank you. Here is a screenshot https://imghostr.com/223bc3_w7z My Excel is not in English but it says 'There is a problem in this formula'.

Comment: Ah, that's probably a difference in our Windows region settings for list separator. Try this formula which uses semicolons instead: `=IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("tax";L10)));NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("usa";M10))));"VAT";"")`

Comment: Great, it works like magic :) Thank you very much, you have no idea how much you helped me.  Is it possible to make it more complex? For example, is it possible to add 'OR'?
"USA" or "UK" or "CA".
And can it be made positive, if it's USA or UK or CA, fill in 'VAT', and if it's AU, fill in 'Tax free'.

Comment: @YSegal There's the straightforward but long way: `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("tax";L10));"";IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("AU";M10)));"Tax free";IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("usa";M10)));NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("uk";M10)));NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("ca";M10))));"VAT";"")))` and there's the fancier but shorter and easier to expand way: `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("tax";L10));"";IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("AU";M10)));"Tax free";IF(SUMPRODUCT(1*NOT(ISERR(SEARCH({"usa";"uk";"ca"};M10))))>0;"VAT";"")))`. I would use the second option, myself.

Answer (score -2):

Color wise you are probably best using a conditional format on the column or cell.

Formula wise. Try this. =IF(SEARCH("tax",M10,1),IF(N10="USA","VAT"," "),"")

[image]

Comment: `" "` ≠ `""`. The cell references are different than OP's. `M10` needs to only contain `USA`, not equal `USA`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @BradR, for some reason I get an error message about this formula too. I'm probably doing something wrong.